# What do you call the art of 'proper' bearing? (French 'maintien')

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, french

An aristocrat, model, steward… will learn about **walking, sitting, behaving**, etc. according to a certain etiquette.

I am not talking about protocol, conversation and etiquette in general - just the physical aspects (e.g. sitting upright, balancing the body a certain way when you walk, etc.)

So if one wants to learn to do that, one takes lessons in ______.

- The French word for this is *maintien* (as in *maintien du corps*) : *cours de maintien*, *professeur de maintien*…
- Google and deepl suggest *maintenance course* or *retention course* but I think that's silly.
- I am thinking about *composure*, *bearing*, *poise*, but these sound to me like qualities rather than crafts. Does it not sound weird to take "lessons in bearing" or "lessons in poise"?

Any flavour of English (US, UK…) would do for me. It could also be that there is no equivalent of the French word in English.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would suggest **deportment**. Oxford Dictionaries says that the meaning of *the way a person stands and walks, particularly as an element of etiquette* is a particularly British usage. My old French dictionary gives it as one of the translations of *maintien.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109357/discussion-on-answer-by-kate-bunting-what-do-you-call-the-art-of-proper-bearin).

Comment: *[Déportement](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9portement)* is mostly unknown in modern French but when it is, the meaning is always negative, more like *bad behavior* or *move away*.  It ceased to have the neutral *maintien* meaning around the 16th century. Your French dictionary must be really old ;-)

Comment: @Jlliagre It's a French-English dictionary. I meant that it translates _maintien_ with the English word _deportment_!

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes more sense!

Answer (score 16):

In English, maintien is called **posture:** The idea is to have **good or proper posture.**

Also, there is good bearing, to have good bearing but that is not good for a course name and is old fashioned

The modern term for that is to carry oneself:
**X will learn how to carry themselves**.

In the 19th c. one would have said: good or proper carriage.

composure is for job interviews and means not to lose one's cool, poise is generally associated with ladies and good bearing is how a person carries him or herself in general.

Posture Training

[posture training](https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/wwii-workout-week-posture-training/)

Comment: The English word *posture* says nothing about it being ***proper***. You are having to qualify it with an adjective to make that clear. But *deportment* specifically does commonly include the meaning of etiquette, and so it doesn't normally require an adjective.

Comment: The OP made clear that she or he **just wants the physical part**. Un bon maintien=good posture

Comment: That's not how I interpret what was asked (emphasis and addition mine): "*I am not talking about protocol, conversation and etiquette **in general** - just the **physical aspects** [of protocol, conversation, and etiquette].*"

Comment: @JasonBassford Right, she is not talking about deportment. She is talking about un bon maintien, good posture. **In French and in English, you have to add an adjective**. I don't understand what you are **on about**. cours de maintien [corporel is a course of good posture. As a title,in English you do need an adjective.

Comment: That's right. You have to say ***good*** *posture*, because *posture*, on its own, is neutral. You have to qualify it with an adjective, like *good* or *bad*. But *deportment* normally contains *good* as part of its meaning. It's assumed that when you say *deportment* it means "proper." That's why as a *single word*, *deportment* conveys more essential information than does *posture*. In short, an adjective is not required with the other word—at least not unless you want to go against the common meaning and specify a negative deportment.

Comment: @JasonBassford Deportment does not work here: **it is old fashioned, precious,  *passé*** and literary (except maybe in certain British circles) and inappropriate for the name of a course in English in our times. I am having a very  hard time with you all (you, Kate. the upvoters and the OP). No one uses the word deportment seriously or other than tongue in cheek today. Crikey, mate. Who the heck would upvote it?

Comment: If people are going to make assumptions and persist on using the word *deportment*, I'm not going to understand them, even after having read this entire page. I'm going to have to go with the person who speaks four languages, +1. How you *deport* (archaic) "conduct oneself in a specified manner", is *'how you carry yourself'*.

Comment: Another way "posture" fails to indicate the OP's meaning: the OP needs a word for what an aristocrat or steward learns, to walk, sit, stand etc. properly. Someone learning about posture might be learning how to stand and walk while carrying a heavy load, or how to sit in an office chair for hours every working day without injuring their back.

Comment: @Lambie The OP needs a word for what an aristocrat or steward learns... Courses in this are an old-fashioned thing more likely to be taken by the upper class. If the word sounds old-fashioned or precious, that's because of the nature of the *thing*, not the *word*.

Comment: @RosieF Exactly — the context of my post is to write fiction about an aristocrat in training, so an old-fashioned-sounding word will fit in nicely. I'm happy with both `good posture` and `deportment`. I didn't think my question would cause a debate, but it has been a very interesting read!

Comment: "maintien is called posture" that's totally incorrect, ask any bilingual person

Comment: @mcadorel You should have said **that** in your question. What a waste of time. And you mean valets/butlers, not stewards. In other words *Downtown Abbey*, both the servants and masters where the masters learn from parents and nannies and the servants learn from other servants. As for models, it does not apply. Perhaps you are thinking of that **outdated practice called coming out and débutantes**.

Comment: @Lambie They *did* say that.  It's literally the first line in the question: *"An aristocrat, model, steward… will learn about walking, sitting, behaving, etc. according to a certain etiquette."*  Besides, Australian high schools still (well, maybe not this year) host "debutante balls", so you can't discard a word and practice *currently regularly use in a rather large country* as "outdated".  (In America, it would often be called a "cotillion", but [not always](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Debutante_Ball))

Comment: @Chronocidal The question was not clear. deportment à la Downton Abbey was not taught via classes (cours in French!). And the ridiculous, outdated débutante thing exists in the US, too. It is still really stupid as it is really about showing off girls in order to marry them off.

Comment: @Lambie In other words, it's basically just an in-person Tinder?  Posh speed-dating?  The need that the event fulfils clearly hasn't gone away, so I don't see how it could be considered outdated or obsolete.  A fancy affectation, perhaps, but so too is much hipster culture.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the answer

## poise

has been deleted.

"Deportment" is correct, but for 99.9% of English-speakers it is an archaic, "intellectual" fancy term.

(Indeed - 70% of English speakers would assume "deportment" is one of those "fancy French words" that intellectual posh people use, like "bon appetit" or "say lah vee" or "sauce".)

Given that "deportment" is way outside the general intellectual / vocabulary range, indeed "poise" is a great choice - "Jane has poise" has the exact sense the OP wants.

Note too that simply "bearing" works.

(You often hear "**military bearing**", Steve has military bearing.

And there's an idiomatic phrase, the **way he holds himself**, and also **the way he carries himself**.

I appreciate OP is actually asking for the "art of..." the system and effort towards poise, bearing.

This concept literally does not exist in the anglophone sphere.

(Even the concept of "éleve", raise a child, is completely different. In French it means steward, herd, form - in the anglophone sphere it means "the party who pays for rent and food while the human moves from 1 yr to 18 yrs of age". You can't really translate "élever un enfant" to "raise a child", you have to go to "pastoral care" or "formed the man..." or such.)

Exactly as the OP says,

> I am thinking about composure, bearing, poise, but these sound to me like qualities rather than crafts. Does it not sound weird to take lessons in bearing or lessons in poise ?

The nearest concept in English is "**finishing school**". In stories when a typically 17 yr old female is "sent to finishing school" (which would be either in (a) Paris or (b) "Switzerland") she is taught how to "walk with a book on her head" (you know?) which is the closest concept in the anglophone sphere.

In the deep South in the US, there are **still a few clubs**, courses, usually labelled something like "Miss Jane's Manners for Young Ladies" or indeed using the word "deportment" (recalling there is still some Frenchish language kicking about in the South) ... "Miss Jane's deportment classes". Instead of say a dance class or soccer on Saturday mornings, youngsters will go to Miss Jane's and literally do the book on the head thing, be drilled in posture, and indeed have a table meal where you learn formal table manners.

Comment: Not all concepts are one word. And I would be careful to say it does not exist "in the anglophone sphere" (English-speaking world). And also, I would be careful to state what 70% of English speakers would say about the word deportment. How can you possibly know that? Enfin, faut pas penser que tu es la seule qui parle deux langues.